# Add custom filed in default registration form magento

Tags: forms, register

I want to add some input fields in magento default registration. Is there any module to add fields in registration from admin panel?

Comment: If you are not planning to update mangento version, then changing core files would be easiest and fast way to do this.

Comment: Did you manage to get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 4):

If you do a Google Search on `Magento customer attributes` you'll get quite a large selection of attributes.

- [AheadWorks customer attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-by-aheadworks.html)
- [Customer Information Collection](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-information-collection-using-customer-attributes.html)
- [Amasty Customer Attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-by-amasty.html)

I've only used the one from Aheadworks which worked pretty well. But as always, I'd suggest testing it on a dev environment first